# Push notifications in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, push-notification

How can I send push notifications from my node js app?
I am using express as the framework and mongoDB as the database.
I want to use it to send OTP to the customer signing up for my app.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of  notification can be implemented using [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io). It allows you to emit an event to all connected clients.

```
var io = require('socket.io')();    
io.emit('an event sent to all connected clients');
```

Comment: I want to send notification when a particular user tries to sign up. Will this work in such a case?
what all inputs would I need to provide?

Comment: You can send notification to a client on connection `var io = require('socket.io')();
  io.on('connection', function(client){
    client.emit('an event', { some: 'data' });
  });`

Comment: Can I send the notification whenever the uses presses a specific button?
I want the user to request for OTP. When they click on the button, i have a separate function in node that will run. Through this code, I want to send notification to the user. is it possible?

Comment: If I understand it correctly in this particular scenario you don't need push notification because you want to send message to client after he clicks button, so what you need to do is react on button event, call your separate function in node and response with message to the client.

Comment: Well thats exactly what needs to be done. Sending message was an option. but twilio charges a lot for this. As it is just my first and a trial app, I prefer finding ways where this can be done for free.

Comment: Could you suggest anything better?

Comment: Bro could you please help with this?

Comment: Am really stuck

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your problem now. I am not sure if I can help. If you really need a push notification I would check socket.io library or similar that allows you to do that but if you need reacts when client clicks button you can run your code and in response returns what you need, without push notificaiton.

Comment: See the thing is, when the user clicks on "Register", I have to send him an OTP. What method you suggest for it?